# Is there any workaround for using Append blob in Azure Data Factory copy?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I don't want my copy data activity in ADF pipeline to overwrite a blob file but instead, append the new data to it. But ADF only supports Blockblob so is there a way to append data to an existing file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Web Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) instead of Copy Activity. Using [Blob Service Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api) you could send a PUT request with data you want to append to a blob.
You can optionally consume datasets and linked services by this activity.

**JSON:**

```
{  
   "name":"AppendDataActivity",
   "type":"WebActivity",
   "typeProperties":{  
      "method":"Put",
      "url":"https://<myAccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<myContainer>/<myBlob><SASToken>&comp=appendblock",
      "headers":{  
         "Content-Type":"application/json" 
      },
      "datasets":[  
         {  
            "referenceName":"<consumedDatasetName>",
            "type":"DatasetReference",
            "parameters":{  
               ...
            }
         }
      ],
      "linkedServices":[  
         {  
            "referenceName":"<consumedLinkedServiceName>",
            "type":"LinkedServiceReference"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

*Note that Body can only support JSON object or JSON value, JSON array is being fixed but non-JSON values aren't supported. For this workaround you could use an Azure Function as endpoint, where you could append files or whatever you want.*