# appending to a file in azure data lake using data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am running into issues while appending data to a file in azure data lake, using data factory.
I am trying to get data from MS Graph API and I am able to get the data and copy it for Single API calls where I push the response to the data lake, using "Copy Data" functionality, but if I want to do multiple calls where I get a response, and then append these responses to a single file, I am not sure how to do that. I don't think the "Copy data" activity is the right action for it.

**One Example:
API to get all groups in tenant:**

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Groups/

**API to get all members associated with a group:**

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/"GroupID"/owners](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%22GroupID%22/owners)

**"Group ID" comes from the top API call.****

I am able to build a loop and do the calls correctly.
It is just appending the results of the second call where I am at a loss. I don't think creating a new file for each group would be the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a couple issues to contend with. First, standard Blobs don't support append operations. For that you'll need an AppendBlob. The second problem is that ADF doesn't support AppendBlob.

Here is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61174460/append-data-to-existing-file-in-azure-data-lake-storage-from-rest-api) where I discuss Copy activity and AppendBlob.

Here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859958/is-there-any-workaround-for-using-append-blob-in-azure-data-factory-copy) (not mine) with an interesting approach that uses the native REST API to append the blob.

Another option would be to let the process create a new file per run. After they've all been created, you could use DataFlow to collapse them into a single file.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I changed my approach to use azure function inside the data factory pipeline to do the heavy lifting, and then data flow to merge results.